# FME wont create the data files correctly?

Tags: fme-form

I try to create the georeferencing files which contains only the one text line like the bounding box coordinates and name (ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax, name) (like: 6635000 3270000 6640000 3275000 18n1a2a).

I create text line using StringConcatenator which connects straight to data writer (Data File). I suppose that it only create file but nothing inside. I am also using AttributeFileWriter in parallel.

[image]

This process creates only 100 Data Files. After that it show me error message:

BADNEWS: File C:\Program Files\FME\metafile\MULTI_WRITER.fmf could not be opened (tabrdr.cpp:161)

Anyone who has done similar data files in FME?

[image]

Comment: looks like your attributes are not mapped correctly (try right clicking the writer and copy from transformer) if you want your coordinates to be in a text_line your need to use the https://www.safe.com/transformers/string-concatenator/

Answer (score 2):

The dark arrow in the writer, "data_file_data", is dark colored. This means the attribute does not contain any data. I don't have any experience with the "Data File" writer, so I can't help with that, but I suspect you will get better results this attribute exists on the feature.

Personally, writing text files, I would use a "Text File" writer. Then the attribute you need is "text_line_data". Just change the output attribute in the StringConcatenator.

The

```
BADNEWS: File C:\Program Files\FME\metafile\MULTI_WRITER.fmf could not
be opened (tabrdr.cpp:161)
```

messages probably appear due to the logging level being set to Debug. Tools, options, tab translation, checkbox debug. Make sure it is checked off. It is a common misunderstood issue, see [this topic on the Safe Software Forum](https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/44058/badnews-file-dappsfmemetafilemulti-writerfmf-could.html).

Comment: I agree. The Data File format is more meant for raw, binary data I believe. The Text File format would be more appropriate here. And - as mentioned - there is no schema mapping to send the data to the output anyway.